# Importing data from 2 spreadheets in Excel to a single table in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, import, vba, ms-access-2007

I am trying to import data from 2 excel spreadsheets into a single table in MS Access 2007.

The data from the spreadsheets has a common record - Number. Spreadsheet 2 may have many different sets of data for each number.

Spreadsheet 1 is in the form:

```
Number    Manager    Location
001       J.Stokes   London
002       B.Johnson  Surrey
003       A.Evans    Bath
```

Spreadsheet 2 is in the form

```
Number    Date      Cost
001       4/8/14    £ 123
002       1/11/14   £ 500
002       5/11/14   £ 250
003       12/12/14  £ 350
```

When I import the data into 2 different tables and run an append query into 1 table, I get the following result

```
Number    Manager    Location    Date       Cost
001       J.Stokes   London      
001                              04/08/14   £ 123
002       B.Johnson  Surrey     
002                              01/11/14   £ 500
002                              05/11/14   £ 250
003       A.Evans    Bath
003                              12/12/14   £ 350
```

How can I manipulate it into the following form?

```
Number    Manager     Location    Date       Cost
001       J.Stokes    London      04/08/14   £ 123
002       B.Johnson   Surrey      01/11/14   £ 500
002       B.Johnson   Surrey      05/11/14   £ 250
003       A.Evans     Bath        12/12/14   £ 350
```

Thanks in advance,
Rob

Comment: The way I see it is wrong structure. It should stay the way it is, two tables linked by the Number on a One to Many relationship style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a relationship between NUMBER on each table and then produced a simple select query. This displays the data in the form I want.

Answer (score -1):

It looks to me like you might find it easiest to import the tables separately then create a query with a Left Join on Spreadsheet1 to put them together.  Kinda like:

```
SELECT
  ss1.Number
, ss1.Manager
, ss1.Location
, ss2.Date
, ss2.Cost
FROM Spreadsheet1 AS ss1
LEFT JOIN Spreadsheet2 AS ss2
ON ss1.Number=ss2.Number
```

Comment: I would not suggest this method, as the OP needs to understand the real DB Normalization process. The data represents that the tables can be diluted, instead of heaping them together.